# Security with PDO select querys?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, prepare

Could anyone help me with my query?

I am currently converting all my old PHP code to use PDO.
I was wondering when is it necessary to use the prepare function for my querys?

I currently have this query.

```
    $sql = "SELECT deckName FROM decks WHERE deleted = '0' ORDER by deckName";
```

None of it is dynamic apart from maybe the deleted column. 
I am using the below to reiterate my data on screen.

```
   foreach($DBH->query($sql) as $row){ echo $row['deckName']?> }
```

Should I still be using this as good practice or is the above good enough?

```
   $sth = $DBH->prepare("SELECT deckName FROM decks WHERE deleted = '0' ORDER by deckName");
```

I am not quite sure how to use the fetch statement correctly when reiterating data from the row?

Thanks in advance :)
Hayley

Comment: [If no variables are going to be used in the query, you can use the PDO::query() method.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query)

Comment: Use prepare when you need to bind the user data inside a query , else you can go for first example.

Comment: I will check out your link Your Common Sense. Looks like a good resource.

Comment: Also, you don't have to use the ugly `while` or `foreach` syntax that's present with `mysql_` or `mysqli_*` extensions in order to loop and retrieve records. Simply use `$records = $DBH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and majority of your code can become one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

If you send a constant string to the database and do never mix in "untrusted input" the security concern is in my experience irrelevant, and only a potential performance aspect remains, which depends on the underlying database. IF the preparation step of an expensive to parse query may be spared for the execute phase (prepare, bind=NOOP here, execute) of all invocations after the first.

So guessing from the tags, that you use mysql and do not use memcached or the like as an intermediate layer, you might just want to measure the performance, otherwise you could migrate to direct queries.

When the "Project" later needs variable parametrization of the query (based on untrusted input e.g. from the network), you should use again prepare, to shield against injection attacks. Maybe then it will be good to find out "how to use the fetch statement correctly when reiterating data from the row" ...

Amending to the answer to accomodate the "uppercased nevers" for using variables in queries from the comments:

There is a practical reason for me writing "receiving untrusted input" instead of "never this and never that". In my experience there is a slippery slope, when it comes to variables: Without auditing the wider context of the $sql variable in above question - even the whole query is potentially vulernable to injection attacks. 
Also internal refactorings of building query strings from constants may lead to mixing further variables to compose a (more complex) string that acts as a query.

For a more balanced / gap minimizing hardening I would suggest:

1. Documenting a specific map of say "trusted boundaries" in a code realizing an app, and based on that, enforcing strict validation of any input crossing these boundaries - i.e. variables transporting values accross - is in most cases effective and efficient.
2. Adding the common sense concept of layered security / separation of concerns will then naturally lead to using prepared statements when "such input" (that crossed a boundary) is to be "injected" as parameter.

I am reluctant to hand out simple recipes giving an optimistic sense of security, when one deals with such a scyscraper like application stack as db based web apps usually do.

Comment: What performance issues you propose to test? The performance of repeating the same constant query again and again? I can tell you without any tests that you have to run this query only ONCE and thus there is nothing to test at all.

Comment: Speaking of the parametrization, talking of "untrusted inputs" is but a grave delusion. One should never be musing on the data origins, but use parameters unconditionally.

Comment: Well, it may be asimplified query, edited for public, or ease of reading, only the OP knows, and then it is good to know, that one can measure, and decide no matter, duration / latency is always easy to interpret - security as in avoiding gaps - is not. And untrusted input is what it is all about. If it is not there, ok, but easy to forget, when allowing variables later in the process ..

Comment: Thanks, I had my suspicion it was that and yes I do use mysql and have no idea what memcached is.

I am very new to databases.

Comment: The data is used for reading only. The code within the foreach creates li's and links to other pages using the deckName.

Comment: So we have a solution. Great. Happy hacking!

Comment: Again, you should NEVER allow a variable in the query, be it trusted or untrusted, input or output. See the point now?

Comment: So, now your answer says "do something to make your code secure but I can't tell you what".

Comment: @YourCommonSense no, it says: there are no good or bad variables, the code using them needs consideration to harden the app. As displayed it is reasonable to assume query($sql) to be "safe 'nuff", combining $sql with other variables carrying value that might have been tampered with **not**. It is not Legoland(tm), it's language land ;-)

Comment: These ideas of yours are a straight way to an insecure code. But it's up to you.